# Re-upload app in different developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval, app-store-connect

I recently tried transferring an app to another Apple Developer ID, but due to issues regarding App Store Connect not realising I've deleted all builds I've been unable to transfer it. I've contacted Apple, but they have no been apple to help me yet. My question is this: Am I able to remove my app from sale, change the bundle ID etc and upload from another Developer ID? I'm worried it will work but get rejected as it will be too similar (in fact the exact same) as my app under my other ID, which I deleted before. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Transferring of the approved app should have worked easily. deleting build has nothing to do with it. Do you have an approves version of that app? If so just go through the transfer process and as far as I remember(did transfer couple of apps 2 3 years back, and that went smoothly) it will take some time to complete that. but Email notification will update you on everything. There won't be an issue for existing users. you can just start using the new account's certificate once transfer complete.

Comment: @RJE na. I have transferred normally and smoothly in the past, however, this one is playing up. I do have to do with the builds because you can't transfer unless you delete all previous test flight builds.

Comment: If that's the case and apple side has a bug, you can update a version with a new build and transfer tomorrow with the new version :)

Comment: @RJE nope. I tried doing that multiple time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I hope its working now, but you can delete app from your apple developer account and upload build to new developer account =, with changing in Ski and bundleId of the app. App should be archived with new bundleId and certificates of new developer account. Also need to change the app name before archiving it.